# What's the Azure equivalent (if any) of %IIS_BIN%\asp.dll?

Tags: azure, asp-classic

For the short-term we need to support a Classic ASP app on our site which is hosted in Azure. However, we also need to support redirecting a client's old ASP pages to the new routes. It's a multitenant site so we're not using IIS rewrites for redirecting old client pages.

So we have the following handler defined:

```
<add name="OldAppASP" path="oldapp/*.asp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%IIS_BIN%\asp.dll" resourceType="File"/>
```

While the above works fine for development using IIS Express locally, it fails in Azure. I assume it's because %IIS_BIN%\asp.dll doesn't exist (or at the least the environment variable is not valid).

We use the above to prevent ASP pages from the legacy app from being needlessly processed by our redirect handler.

Is there an Azure equivalent for %IIS_BIN%\asp.dll that I can use?

Thank you!

PS: I continue my search online as well. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production deployment, I was able to use `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll` which resolved my issue.